# Too many values to unpack in Django

Tags: reactjs, django, react-redux

My endpoint to edit a user in Django is implemented like this:

```
@api_view(['PUT'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def updateUser(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(pk)

    data = request.data
    user.first_name = data['name']
    user.username = data['email']
    user.email = data['email']
    user.is_staff = data['isAdmin']

    user.save()
    serializer = UserSerializer(user, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

My user serializer is implemented like this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    _id = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    isAdmin = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', '_id', 'username', 'email', 'name', 'isAdmin']

    def get__id(self, obj):
        return obj.id

    def get_isAdmin(self, obj):
        return obj.is_staff

    def get_name(self, obj):
        name = obj.first_name
        if name == '':
            name = obj.email
        return name
```

My action in Redux to send a put request to Django is implemented like this:

```
export const updateUser = (user) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
        dispatch({
            type: USER_UPDATE_REQUEST
        })

        const {
            userLogin: { userInfo
            }
        } = getState()

        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`
            }
        }

        const { data } = await axios.put(
            `/api/users/update/${user._id}/`,
            user,
            config
        )

        dispatch({
            type: USER_UPDATE_SUCCESS,
        })

        dispatch({
            type: USER_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
        })

    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: USER_UPDATE_FAIL,
            payload: error.response && error.response.data.detail
                ? error.response.data.detail
                : error.message,
        })
    }
}
```

I dispatch updateUser action on click of the button in my component like this:

```
const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    dispatch(updateUser({ _id: user._id, name, email, isAdmin }))
}
```

I get error from Django:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/users/update/undefined/ Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)   File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)       File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)   File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)   File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc   File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)         File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\ecommerce\backend\base\views\user_views.py", line 94, in updateUser
    user = User.objects.get(pk)   File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 482, in get
    clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1071, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)   File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1089, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)   File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1096, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))   File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1502, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)   File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1532, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(      File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1374, in build_filter
    arg, value = filter_expr ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)     [16/Dec/2022 10:32:19] "PUT /api/users/update/undefined/ HTTP/1.1" 500 133599
```

Please help me understand where the problem is

Comment: paste  `UserSerializer`  as well.  You are saving user obj without validating?

Comment: upd: added a UserSerializer

Comment: Post the complete error message with trace back.

Comment: upd: added a traceback text

Comment: Please format it as *code*, not as quote, to preserve the original formatting that makes it more readable…

Comment: upd: tracebak text formatted as a code

Comment: That's not really the original formatting, but okay, fine. @Ezon shows you in the answer below what you're missing. Apparently you're also sending "`undefined`" instead of the user id in the URL though, which is some bug on the Javascript side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the first line of your view function:

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
```

-- Explaination --

`.get` require keyword arguments.

Comment: A little more explanation on what exactly was wrong would be good.

Comment: thnx, you solved it